# Firebase Auth Email issue - Index.js errors when deploying

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I'm getting errors with the Index.js cloned from a project. It's a Firebase projects, and this is supposed to use Firebase Functions (nodemailer) to send out a verification email with a token used to verify the created account. My code is on the top, errors below:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var cors = require('cors');
const secureCompare = require('secure-compare');

// Configure the email transport using the default SMTP transport and a GMail account.
// For other types of transports such as Sendgrid see https://nodemailer.com/transports/
// TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.
const gmailEmail = encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.email);
const gmailPassword = encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.password);

const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
  `smtps://${gmailEmail}:${gmailPassword}@smtp.gmail.com`);

const APP_NAME = 'The Ride Share';

//admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
// var firebaseConfig = functions.config().firebase;
// firebaseConfig.databaseAuthVariableOverride = {
//   uid: 'fbcfunction',
// };

admin.initializeApp();


function sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName, token) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'The Ride Share',
    to: email
  };

  // The user unsubscribed to the newsletter.
  mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;
  mailOptions.text = `Hey ${displayName}!, Welcome to ${APP_NAME}. Your token is ${token}, Please enter the token in the portal to verify the account.`;
  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
    console.log('New welcome email sent to:', email);
  });
}

exports.prepareVerificationMail = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/shellMailId')
  .onWrite((change,context)=>{
    console.log('event', change);
    console.log('Mail id is', change.after.val());
    if (change.after.val() != null) {
      return change.after.parent.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log('snapval is the user id', snapshot.key);
        var userId = snapshot.key;
        //console.log('this is the userId', userId);
        return userId;
      }).then(function (userId) {
        console.log('this should be user id', userId);

        return admin.database().ref().child('userTokens').child(userId).child('token').once('value')
          .then(function (token) {
            console.log('this is the token', token);
            var displayName = change.after.val().toString();
            if (displayName.indexOf('@') > -1) {
              displayName = displayName.substring(0, displayName.indexOf('@'));
            }
            console.log('displayName', displayName);
            return sendWelcomeEmail(change.after.val(), displayName, token.val());
          }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('error in reading the user token', error);
            return;
          });

      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('error in getting user key', error);
        return;
      });
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });

exports.setTheToken = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/personalEmail')
  .onWrite((change,context)=>{

    console.log('event data val', change.after.val());
    console.log(change);
    if (change.after.val() != null) {
      //
      return change.after.parent.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log('snapval is the user id', snapshot.key);
        var userId = snapshot.key;
        //console.log('this is the userId', userId);
        return userId;
      }).then(function (userId) {
        console.log('this should be user id', userId);  
        var token = parseInt(Math.random() * 100000);
        console.log('this is the token', token);
        return admin.database().ref().child('userTokens').child(userId).child('token').set(token).then(function (success) {

          console.log('success token set');
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log('Error token not set', error);
        });
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error token not set', error);
      });
      //TOKEN PREVIOUSLY DOESNT EXIST THEN CREATE AND ASSIGN

    }
    else {
      console.log('personal email field value not present');
      return;
    }
  });


exports.removeActiveRequests = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const key = req.query.key;

  // Exit if the keys don't match
  if (!secureCompare(key, functions.config().cron.key)) {
    console.log('The key provided in the request does not match the key set in the environment. Check that', key,
      'matches the cron.key attribute in `firebase env:get`');
    res.status(403).send('Security key does not match. Make sure your "key" URL query parameter matches the ' +
      'cron.key environment variable.');
    return;
  }

  console.log('delete all the active requests here');
  var userSeatsToUpdate = [];
  var firebaseRef = admin.database().ref().child('requests');

  return firebaseRef.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
      if (userSeatsToUpdate.indexOf(child.val().requestedTo) < 0) {
        userSeatsToUpdate.push(child.val().requestedTo);
      }
    });
    return userSeatsToUpdate;
  }).then(function (success) {
    var promises = success.map(function (key) {
      return admin.database().ref().child('users').child(key).once("value");
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);
  }).then(function (snapshots) {
    var updates = {};
    snapshots.forEach(function (snapshot) {
      updates[snapshot.key + "/remainingSeats"] = snapshot.val().capacity;
    });
    return updates;

  }).then(function (listToUpdate) {
    var ref = admin.database().ref().child('users');
    return ref.update(listToUpdate);
  }).then(function (success) {
    console.log('success', success);
    //Add logic to move active requests to past requests, may for analytics    
    return firebaseRef.remove()    
  }).then(function(sucess) {
    console.log('active requests deleted', success);
    res.status(200).send('All requests are deleted');
  }).fcatch(function (error) {
    console.log('error:nightlyJob:', error);
    res.status(400).send('error', error);
  });

});



// CORS and Cloud Functions export logic
exports.verifyToken = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var corsFn = cors();
  corsFn(req, res, function () {
    verifyTheUserToken(req, res);

  });
});


function verifyTheUserToken(req, res) {

  console.log('in verify token');
  if (req.method === 'PUT') {
    res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
  }

  if (!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    console.error('No Firebase ID token was passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization header.',
      'Make sure you authorize your request by providing the following HTTP header:',
      'Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>');
    res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
  }



  const firebaseToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
  const userId = req.body.uid;
  const receievedToken = req.body.token;

  return admin.auth().verifyIdToken(firebaseToken).then(decodedFirebaseToken => {
    console.log('ID Token correctly decoded', decodedFirebaseToken);
    console.log('req', req.body);
    return 'sucess';

  }).then(function (receivedValues) {

    return admin.database().ref().child('userTokens').child(userId).child('token').once('value');

  }).then(function (snapshot) {

    console.log('this is the snap', snapshot);
    if (!snapshot.val()) {
      return Promise.reject('token is not set ');
    }

    console.log('snapshot.val(): ', snapshot.val(), 'receievedToken :', receievedToken);
    if (snapshot.val() != receievedToken) {
      return Promise.reject('token doesnt match');
    }

    return 'verified';

  }).then(function (sucess) {

    return admin.database().ref().child('users').child(userId).child('isVerified').set(true);

  }).then(function (sucess) {
    //DO A REDIRECT
    console.log('success in setting verified to true');
    res.send();
  }).catch(function (error) {
    //DECIDE WHAT YOU WANT TO DO
    console.log('Error', error);
    return admin.database().ref().child('users').child(userId).child('isVerified').set(true).then(function (success) {
      console.log('Setting verified to false');
      res.send();
    }).catch(function (error) {
      //DECIDE WHAT YOU WANT TO DO
      console.log('Error in setting false', error);
      res.send();
    });

  });

}


exports.handleRequestsForCarpooling = functions.database.ref('/requests/{uid}/')
  .onWrite((change,context)=>{

    console.log('new val', change.after.val());
    console.log('old val', change.before.previous.val());

    var rootRef = change.before.adminRef.root.child("users");

    if (change.after.val() !== null) {
      if (change.before.previous.val() !== null) {
        let firebaseRef = rootRef.child(change.before.previous.val().requestedTo).child('remainingSeats');

        firebaseRef.transaction(function (remainingSeats) {
          console.log('remainingSeats11111', remainingSeats);
          return remainingSeats + 1;
        }).then(function (success) {

          console.log('sucss', success);
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.warn('error', error);
        });
      }
      let firebaseRef = rootRef.child(change.after.val().requestedTo).child('remainingSeats');
      firebaseRef.transaction(function (remainingSeats) {
        console.log('remainingSeats', remainingSeats);
        return remainingSeats - 1;
      }).then(function (success) {

        console.log('req', success);
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.warn('error', error);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('no data');

    }

  });


exports.setRemainingSeatsOnCapacityChange = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/capacity')
  .onWrite((change,context)=>{

    if (change.before.previous.val() == change.after.val())
      return;

    var userId = '';

    if (change.before && change.after.val() != null) {
      return change.after.adminRef.parent.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log('snapval is the user id', snapshot.key);
        userId = snapshot.key;
        console.log('userid', userId);
        return userId;
      }).then(function (userId) {
        return admin.database().ref().child('requests').orderByChild("requestedTo").equalTo(userId).once('value');

      }).then(function (snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.val())
          return Object.keys(snapshot.val()).length;
        else
          return 0;
      }).then(function (activeRequest) {
        var userRef = admin.database().ref().child("users").child(userId);
        console.log('this is the capacity', change.after.val());
        console.log('this is the activeRequest', activeRequest);
        var remainingSeats = change.after.val() - activeRequest;
        return userRef.update({
          remainingSeats: remainingSeats,
        });
      }).then(function (success) {
        console.log('success');
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error('error:', error);

      });
    }
  });
```

> i  deploying database, functions, hosting Running command: npm
>   --prefix "functions" run lint
>
> > functions@ lint c:\ridesmartnew\functions
> >     eslint .
>
> c:\ridesmartnew\functions\index.js    44:51   error    Each then()
>   should return a value or throw            promise/always-return
>   54:23   error    Use '===' to compare with null
>   no-eq-null    54:40   error    Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='
>   eqeqeq    55:60   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback    60:15   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback    63:16
>   warning  Avoid nesting promises
>   promise/no-nesting    63:16   warning  Avoid nesting promises
>   promise/no-nesting    64:17   warning  Unexpected function expression 
>   prefer-arrow-callback    72:20   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback    77:16
>   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback    82:7    warning  Arrow function expected a
>   return value                consistent-return    91:9    error    Use
>   '===' to compare with null                        no-eq-null    91:26 
>   error    Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='                   eqeqeq 
>   93:60   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback    98:15   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   102:16
>   warning  Avoid nesting promises
>   promise/no-nesting   102:16   warning  Avoid nesting promises
>   promise/no-nesting   102:104  warning  Unexpected function expression 
>   prefer-arrow-callback   102:104  error    Each then() should return a
>   value or throw            promise/always-return   105:18   warning 
>   Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   108:16   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   116:7
>   warning  Arrow function expected a return value
>   consistent-return   137:3    warning  Arrow function expected no
>   return value               consistent-return   137:41   warning 
>   Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   138:22   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   144:11
>   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   145:32   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   150:11
>   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   152:23   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   157:11
>   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   160:11   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   164:11
>   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   164:11   error    Each then() should return a
>   value or throw            promise/always-return   167:13   warning 
>   Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   179:20   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   211:11
>   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   215:11   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   219:14
>   error    Expected the Promise rejection reason to be an Error 
>   prefer-promise-reject-errors   223:24   error    Expected '!==' and
>   instead saw '!='                   eqeqeq   224:14   error    Expected
>   the Promise rejection reason to be an Error 
>   prefer-promise-reject-errors   229:11   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   233:11
>   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   233:11   error    Each then() should return a
>   value or throw            promise/always-return   237:12   warning 
>   Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   240:12   warning  Avoid nesting promises
>   promise/no-nesting   240:12   warning  Avoid nesting promises
>   promise/no-nesting   240:100  error    Each then() should return a
>   value or throw            promise/always-return   240:100  warning 
>   Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   243:14   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   266:33
>   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   269:17   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   269:17
>   error    Each then() should return a value or throw
>   promise/always-return   272:18   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   277:31
>   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   280:15   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   280:15
>   error    Each then() should return a value or throw
>   promise/always-return   283:16   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   297:35
>   error    Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                   eqeqeq 
>   302:23   error    Use '===' to compare with null
>   no-eq-null   302:40   error    Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='
>   eqeqeq   303:7    warning  Arrow function expected no return value
>   consistent-return   303:60   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   308:15   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   311:15
>   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   317:15   warning  Unexpected function
>   expression                        prefer-arrow-callback   325:15
>   warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback   325:15   error    Each then() should return a
>   value or throw            promise/always-return   327:16   warning 
>   Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback
>
> ✖ 68 problems (18 errors, 50 warnings)   0 errors, 40 warnings
>   potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! functions@ lint:
>   `eslint .` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   functions@ lint script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with
>   npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Administrator.ME-IT-01\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-06-13T17_24_30_283Z-debug.log
>
> Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero
>   exit code1

Comment: your code didn't pass linting(by eslint) so it didn't deploy, please check the error message line by line and fix accordingly

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite new to this and was hoping to get a bit of input on if there's anything glaring that I'm not seeing. The other thing is, this file deployed yesterday from a different project, but literally copy/paste same as before, so I'm not sure why I'm seeing this issue. Just trying to learn a bit from my mistakes and hoping to get input from people who know this stuff

Comment: since the lint checking is a local (when running gcloud deploy?) check, it is possible that this code runs on cloud no problem, if you somehow managed to skip the linter. e.g. not running npm lint or just deploy it via web console